# What is a "target" in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I would like a simple explanation of what a target is in CMake. The current terminology is something I am not all too familiar with and I am seeking a simple explanation of the word "target" used primarily with `add_executable` and `add_library`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target is a name for something to do. Execute or build or create, depending on the target. Typically, target names represent an executable file or library file.

The term "target" comes from `make` command. `make` takes targets names as arguments and builds them using rules that specify what to do to create a specific target/file. In `make` a "target" is just a path to a file to produce, for example an actual executable name. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction

The build system generated by CMake "updates a target" (executes the commands needed to build the executable file or library file) when the prerequisite files have been modified since the target was last modified or the target does not exist ("the target" = the file that is the result of building the target).

Answer (score 3):

A target represents either an executable (functions and data in a binary that has a main-function/entrypoint (a program)), or a library (functions and data in a binary with no main-function/entrypoint) in a buildsystem. For more information, see [the docs on binary targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#binary-targets), and [the docs for `add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) and [for `add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html).

Targets can be part of a project (in which case they have source files and need to be built as part of the buildsystem), or `IMPORTED`, in which case they already exist in binary form and have no sources and do not need to be built (they were already built outside the buildsystem to be generated for a project).

Targets can have dependencies between them. Ex. An executable target depending on a library target to use its functions and data. For more info, see [the docs for `target_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html), which can have implications for linking binaries together, and for build order: making sure dependent targets are re-built (if needed- which is not always the case, Ex. with non-interface changes to shared libraries) when depended-upon targets need to be rebuilt.

There are some target types which are not `IMPORTED` which also have nothing to build (Ex. [interface libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries), and other types you can read about in the `add_library` docs, but those are more "advanced" features).

Comment: Is their a reason why they decided on the word "target" in this usage? I have not seen it used like this in other examples. When I think of the word "target" it has always meant something such as a goal or object, e.g. "Our **target** to hit is the middle of the dart board" or "Our target is to raise $100". I was failing to think of a sentence such as "Our target is to create an executable or library from these dependencies from our build process". I would have thought a better sentence such as "Our **goal** is to create ...". Maybe my english is a bit off. Thanks again.

Comment: That's a new question. Generally when you have a new question, you should make a new question post, but I think this question is better suited to ask the maintainers of CMake themselves, as I'm not aware of naming rationales like this typically being publicly documented. See discource.cmake.org.